# Xbox Family Safety - Are toddlers really forced to have their own Microsoft account?

Tags: xbox-series-x-series-s

My toddler plays a 4+ game on Xbox. Similar to Nintendo, she uses my account and I have put restrictions on it (at least for Nintendo).

With Microsoft it seems like she has to make her own account and only then I can make restrictions.

But I don't want an own account for my toddler. Is there not another way? I wish that she uses my account.

Comment: Is this really the first Xbox model?

Comment: I edited the tag to better address your problem

Comment: Can't really look now to summarize, but you probably want to start here https://www.xbox.com/en-US/community/for-everyone/responsible-gaming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fellow parent here that went through this a while ago. Restrictions are account based, so you will have to restrict your own account which will lead to other problems. It's advisable to make a different account and then add it "under" your own account. From personal experience this is the best way to go forward since you will have a lot more control over things without affecting your account.